# UIImagePickerViewerController crashes when attempting to go to saved photos (on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerViewerController. It works perfectly when I select `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`. However, when I go try to select `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, it crashes with this error:

```
2011-09-14 01:41:21.779 NG911[378:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera'
```

Here is the code I have:

```
        if(![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] || ![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIAlertView *noCameraAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                message:@"This device does not support a photo library"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [noCameraAlert setTag:2];
        [noCameraAlert show];
        [noCameraAlert release];
        return;
    }

    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    [picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line

```
[picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
```

which is where the exception is thrown, the problem is you cannot set showCameraControls to yes when you are using the album. Just comment that line out and you should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense in theory, but it's still throwing the same exception.

Comment: it shouldnt... i tried it myself, like you have it throws, removing the line fixes it

Comment: My code is now: `NSLog(@"AAAAAA");
        [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        NSLog(@"BBBBB");
        [picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
        NSLog(@"CCCCCC");
        [picker setAllowsEditing:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

Sorry for the formatting, I have trouble with carriage returns in comments (within code). Anyway, my log statements confirm it crashes at the line we expect, but it's still crashing even with this code. Any thoughts?

Comment: like the answer says comment out the cameracontrol line

Comment: Edited your answer for clarification. Didn't know you meant that I had to remove the line completely. Thanks for the tip though! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that you're setting the sourceType to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum regardless of which sourceType is supported.

i.e. The following line should be conditional;

```
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
```

Instead, put in a condition or two, and if the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` exists, then only set the sourceType to this one. Else, if the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` exists, set the sourceType to that one.

Also, I guess [picker setShowsCameraControls:YES]; should be done for the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera sourceType only.

The error you're getting is suggesting that `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` is not supported, so try working it out in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

What  you need to do is... Change your if condition in else if then or.. when

```
if([isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
{

[picker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
}
else
{
[picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
}
```